# Reading apache phoenix table with sparklyr

Tags: apache, apache-phoenix, sparklyr

Can anyone help me on how to read a table on apache phoenix with sparklyr ?

Thanks.

Comment: You will likely need to use the `spark_read_jdbc` function. The details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420958/how-to-use-a-predicate-while-reading-from-jdbc-connection) might give you some hints as to how to do that. (I don't know exactly how.)

Comment: https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html suggests the Spark plugin for Phoenix could be better for some use cases than jdbc